# Change innerHTML onmousemove event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to change the innerHTML of a div with **onmousemove** event.

Let's say that when the mouse move over the div, the innerHTML change to "Mouse is Moving". And when the mouse stop moving it return back to the default innerHTML value: "Mouse is not moving".

Pretty simple. I know there is a **onmouseleave** event you can use to undo **onmouseenter** or **onmouseover** actions but there is no "onmousecalm" event to undo **onmousemove**.

how to achieve that ?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `mousemove` to set the `innerHTML` and every time the event fires, get a timestamp then use a `setInterval` with some sort of threshold to detect when the mouse has stopped moving to reset the `innerHTML`

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div'),
    move = div.getAttribute('data-move'),
    pause = div.innerHTML,
    threshold = 500;

div.addEventListener('mousemove',function() {
  lastMoved = new Date().getTime();
  div.innerHTML = move;
  var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var nowTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (nowTime - lastMoved > threshold) {
      div.innerHTML = pause;
    }
  }, threshold)
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div data-move="mouse is moving">mouse is not moving</div>
```